# Communicate two nodes using Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I'm beginner to Akka and I wanted to make two nodes communicate to each other such that each one do a task in Akka/scala any one know how to start ?

Comment: Two nodes means? you want to create two actor communicating to each other?

Comment: why don't you just go to akka documentation? and see if they know how to start?

Comment: I'm not sure if the nodes could be actors in one actor system or in different one , as I understood from the documentation you should have a cluster contains many actor systems and each actor system contains actors . my question : is it must to create a cluster just to communicate two nodes only ? 
also please if you know another mechanism other than akka to connect two nodes I would be thankful

Comment: two nodes of what?

Comment: tow machines (pc) . more explanation :what I wanted to do create ZIO simple program over two computers

Comment: You may want to use AKKA remoting?

Comment: I had tried this example from Akka doc 
https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=akka&project=akka-samples-cluster-scala 
I put two different IPs  rather than using one computer with two ports it always give me an error , connection refused (timed out) even I increased the time ?

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html. 

Start the app twice changing pot number. In your code, create actor A in one instance and actor B in the other instance, then, use lookup actors, to send messages from A to B 

    val refToActoB = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://actorSystemName@ipB:portB/user/actorB")'